# Как сделать плавное появление?

Tags: css

```
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: wave 4.4s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;

}
```

Сначала появлется сверху и "телепортируется" в середину. Как сделать чтобы или сразу повередине или плавно это было?

Comment: а где ваш элемент?

Comment: Полный код в студию

Comment: @Duoxx :DDDDDDD

Comment: Что смешного???

Comment: <img src="" class="logo">